# How to recover data from Azure Data Storage

Tags: azure, file, storage, azure-data-lake

Need help,

There is a delete process from Databricks Azure that deleted folder from Data Lake - storage Gen1.
There were many files and subfolders in that folder.

How to retrieve that folder to original state?
Do not see 'trashcan' nor 'restore' option anywhere on the folder..

Thank you

Comment: Based on the docs, it seems like it is not possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-disaster-recovery-guidance#data-corruption-or-accidental-deletion-recovery-guidance

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with @hujtomi.

Portal only provide the same [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-disaster-recovery-guidance#data-corruption-or-accidental-deletion-recovery-guidance) for us and we can not find the way to recovery the files:

[image]

**Tell us more about the problem you are experiencing**: Recover deleted file or folder:

[image]

I think the best way is that contact Azure Support in 7 days, if the folder and files are very important, maybe they could help you.